# Generate Prime Numbers With Iterator Protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iterator-protocol

I am trying to get a series of prime numbers from 1 to n. Instead of using a range and for loop, i am trying to implement it using the iterator protocol. So far i have the below, but as you will see, it isn't doing what i expect.

```
class Prime:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.current = 1
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        x = self.current
        self.current += 1
        for num in range(self.current, self.n):
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if num % i == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    return num


d = Prime(20)
c = iter(d)
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
```

it prints 2,3,5,5,7,7
And the goal is for it to print 2,3,5,7,11...19

I just don't want an answer, if you could please explain how too, i would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: SymPy has a module that can do this https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html.

Comment: Thanks for this but i'm not supposed to use modules for this task. Plus i really want to understand the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `next` on the instance you increment `current` so you can start where you left off. Then you proceed to *find* the next prime but don't update `current`.  You can kind of see what is happening if you print `current` with each next call.

```
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')    
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')    # current:5 | next prime: 7
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')    # current:6 | next prime: 7
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')    # current:7 | next prime: 11
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')    # current:8 | next prime: 11
print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}')

...
```

For example if `current` is five then the next prime is seven. `current` is incremented to six then it finds the *next* prime which is also seven.

Remove the statement that increments `current`. Then add a statement to *update* `current` when the *next* prime is found.

```
...
    def __next__(self):
        x = self.current
##        self.current += 1
        for num in range(self.current, self.n):
            if num > 1:
                for i in range(2, num):
                    if num % i == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    self.current = num + 1 
                    return num
```

---

- Printing relevant data/comparisons/... can be a useful tool.
- Stepping through the code with pencil and paper can also be useful - *Be The Interpreter*
- If you are using an IDE, learning its debugging features should be high on a list of priorities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The  "print(f'current:{c.current} | next prime: {next(c)}') " helped with visualization but the code isn't still acting like it should. It was was still repeating prime numbers so i placed the "self.current += 1" right under the first for loop and it worked.
I'm still struggling with the whole idea of implementing this manually. But is it safe to say that the increment must always be placed first under the next method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Prime:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.current = 2
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.current, self.n+1):
            pflag = True
            for j in range(2, i):
                if i%j == 0:
                    pflag=False
                    break
                    
            if pflag:
                self.current=i
                yield i
d = Prime(20)
c = iter(d)
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I believe that's a generator? Because of the yield statement. I can't use it for this specific task.